# jsp page as css file on Tomcat

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat

I want to have a css file which is in fact a jsp-page. One of the reasons is that I would like to use c:url tags to make the path to images context-independent.

So far I only found a possibility to set this up in server.xml. But I need it for my webapp only, and not server-wide.

---

**Update:** Setting the content-type to text/css of course works. But it still leaves me with a style.jsp whereas I want the file to be named style.css. One of the reasons would be that Eclipse's syntax-highlighting and autocompletion do then work.

Answer (score 2):

The file extension is in fact irrelevant. The key is the HTTP [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header. The browser uses this information to treat the response in an appropriate manner.

Put this in top of your to-be-CSS JSP file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/css" %>
```

That's it.

If you leave the manual setting of the HTTP `Content-Type` header away, then the job of setting the `Content-Type` header will be taken over by the servletcontainer/webserver. *This* part is then sniffing the file extension to set the appropriate header.

---

**Update**: as per your update, you want to use the `.css` extension anyway to take benefit of IDE's highlighting and autocompletion. Then there's another way: map the CSS file on the `servlet-name` of the `JspServlet` as it is definied in the particular servletcontainer. In case of Tomcat, it's usually `jsp`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/style.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You should however take into account that the behaviour of your webapp will now be dependent of the servletcontainer in question. There may exist servletcontainers which doesn't use `jsp` as `servlet-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a jsp extension on the file and its reference. You will have to change th mime type in the jsp.